# saving specific bits from a 64-bit long number

Tags: bit-manipulation

I have a 64-bit uint64_t number:

```
Primitive<uint64_t> b = 0xCCCCCCCC00000000;
```

I need to save the first 31 (most important) bits - 7FFFFFFE.

I found this solution in the Internet:

```
start = (((b)>>(first)) & ((1<<(((last+1)-(first))))-1));
```

but in my case for this code:

```
Primitive<uint64_t> start = (((b)>>(32)) & ((1<<(((63+1)-(32))))-1));
```

I get an error: left shift count >= width of type

And even if I change 63 to 62:

```
Primitive<uint64_t> start = (((b)>>(32)) & ((1<<(((62+1)-(32))))-1));
```

I get: error: integer overflow in expression

Any tips? Thanks.

Comment: First of all - specify language and platform you're targeting. When you put numeric characters (such a 1 << 4) most compilers will interpret it as integer by default - while you need them to be uint64_t - so depending on language it will be something like ((uint64_t)1)<<4 instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the most significant 31 bits then:

```
start = (b >> 33) & 0x7ffffffeULL;
```